# what is wrong with this code? adding node after a given value in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

i am using a while to add a node to my linked list after a value provided.
but it is not working accordingly.

I have done print command inside while loop it's showing that it works fine as I want, but when I am printing list it's not.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None


class LInkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def print_list(self):

    cur_node = self.head
    while cur_node:
        print(cur_node.data)
        cur_node = cur_node.next

def apppend(self, data):
    new_node = Node(data)
    if self.head is None:
        new_node = self.head
        return
    last_node = self.head
    while last_node.next is not None:
        last_node = last_node.next
    last_node.next = new_node

def prepend(self, data):
    new_node = Node(data)

    new_node.next = self.head
    self.head = new_node

def add_after_node(self, after, data):
    new_node = Node(data)
    this_node = self.head
    while this_node:

        if this_node.data == after:
            new_node.next = this_node.next
            this_node.next = new_node


        # print(this_node.data) this shows that is updating properly 
        this_node = this_node.next






new_list = LInkedList()
new_list.prepend(10)
new_list.prepend(20)
new_list.prepend(30)
new_list.prepend(20)



new_list.add_after_node(20, 50)
new_list.print_list()
```

I want that 50 should be added after each 20 in the list.
for example:
input :- 20 30 20 10
output :- 20 50 30 20 50 10

right now it is printing 20 50 10 with print_list function I don't know why?

Comment: use `print()` to see what you add after `50`. It seems you don't add old `node.next` which you overwrite by node `50`

Comment: can you explain I didn't understand it.

Comment: you expect two 50 on the list but you create only one `new_node` . You should create `new_node` inside `while True`, every time when you find node 20, not only once before `while True`

Comment: in first comment I was wrong. I read code inside `if` in wrong order so I thoung you do this in wrong way but this is OK. Problem can be that you create only one `Node(data)` but you add it in two places.

Comment: thanks, mate, you are genius, it is working now.